# O que é Level Trust de uma aplicação ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, .net, asp.net, segurança

Para que serve a configuração de Level Trust em uma aplicação ASP.NET?

Ela protege o servidor de alguma coisa?

Ela protege a aplicação de alguma coisa?

Em qual caso ou por qual motivo é recomendado ou necessário alterar essa configuração?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Para que serve a configuração de Level Trust em uma aplicação ASP.NET?

Você determina o que a aplicação pode ou não fazer. Algumas funcionalidades podem ser um pouco perigosas, especialmente se ele puder ser invocada inadvertidamente de forma externa.

Quanto menos confiança você exigir da aplicação mais seguro ela estará (não quer dizer que só isso dá segunrança). Se ela exigir mais que o servidor permite ela não rodará. Se hospeda em um servidor compartilhado, só poderá usar o que eles permitirem.

> Ela protege o servidor de alguma coisa?

Sim, você pode restringir o que as aplicações podem fazer no seu servidor.

> Ela protege a aplicação de alguma coisa?

De certa forma sim, já que se você definir que a aplicação terá um nível limitado que impede ser funcionalidades, a aplicação não funcionará se uma delas for executada por acidente.

> Em qual caso ou por qual motivo é recomendado ou necessário alterar essa configuração?

Em geral é muito útil quando o servidor é compartilhado e você não quer permitir que os outros usuários (desenvolvedores) dele possam fazer qualquer coisa no servidor.

[Documentação dos níveis](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/cc754779(v=ws.11)?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397).

[Mais informações](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/wyts434y(v=vs.140)?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397).

Comment: Que palavra difícil: inadvertidamente! Não conhecia

Comment: Muito obrigado @bigown.